# Ping.Send(ip, timeout) in .Net returns too fast and complains on timeout

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, network-programming

I'm using this method repeatedly in order to monitor connection to machine in the local network. When same test is done from cmd, results are steady and consistent:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping -t 192.168.11.12

Pinging 192.168.11.12 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.11.12: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=126
Reply from 192.168.11.12: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=126
```

But when running from C# with 500 ms timeout it occasionally fails even before the timeout can expire:

```cs
public void TestIpAnswersPing()
{
    var ip = "192.168.11.12";
    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

    var p = new Ping();

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000))
    {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        PingReply reply = p.Send(ip, (int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds);

        if(reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
        {
            Debug.Assert(DateTime.Now - start >= timeout);
        }
    }
}
```

If I change timeout to 1 sec - all pass successfully with average time of pings 0.9 ms.

The only similar thing I have found is this - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533627, which doesn't help much.

Why this might happen and how to monitor high rate connection?

Comment: Maybe because you're blasting it with 1000 simultaneous pings?  The OS might have restrictions on how much you're allowed to ping things.  Your loop isn't sleeping, and you'll probably notice that the ping utility includes a 1 second wait.

Comment: I thought that too, but when timeout is enlarged to 1 sec everything works properly and all the 1000 pings done before 1 second passes. Even more, if reply.Status isn't `IPStatus.Success` it's `IPStatus.Timeout` which is ridiculous.

Comment: Forgot to mention: included function is a test only. The problem occurred in a real program where all proper sleeps were done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fix it with multiple tries.
And don't know if Thread.Sleep(50); is necessary, but it seems to help.

Buffer, TimeOut, TTL are just snakeoil ;)

```
    private PingReply Ping(string ip, int tryCount = 0)
    {
        var ping = new Ping();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65500];

        var pingReply = ping.Send(ip, 500, buffer, new PingOptions(600, false));
        if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            return pingReply;
        }

        if (tryCount < 5)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            return Ping(ip, tryCount + 1);
        }
        return pingReply;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone still has this issue: because of some reason, Thread.Sleep(50) indeed solves the problem.